# String literal not printing out correctly

Tags: c, string, struct

I am trying to build a string in C, and then store that string in a struct. However when I build my string and print it out for testing, I get extra unintelligible characters after the correct string. Any suggestions would be great.

My code

```
typedef struct
{
    char *context;
    int numOnes;
    int numZeros;


}Pattern;
void getPrediction(int t,int *stream){
    int end = beg;
    int count = 0;
    char *pred, str[t+1];
    pred = str;
    int n = t;
    while(count<t){
        //printf("%d\n", stream[end]);
        if(stream[end] == 1){
            pred[count]= '1';
        }
        else{
            pred[count]='0';
        }
        end--;
        n--;
        count++;
    }
    printf("%s\n",pred);
    beg--;
    Pattern newPat={pred,1,0}; //testing purposes
    printf("%s\n",newPat.context); //testing purposes
}
```

Comment: BTW , a *string literal* is `"stuff"` in your source code. Not `pred`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf("%s"` expects a **string** , which is defined as a series of characters followed by a null character. You didn't supply the null character.

To fix this, do `pred[count] = 0;` before the `printf`.